# ORDER BY variable AFTER statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM board") or die(mysql_error());
while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc( $data ))
{ 
if(!empty($info['user'])){
Print "".$info['user'].""; }
else {
}

myOtherQuery($info['id']);
}

function myOtherQuery($id) {

$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(source_user_id) FROM likes 
INNER JOIN pins ON pins.id = likes.pin_id 
WHERE pins.board_id='$id'");
$c = mysql_result($result3, 0); // Cumulative tally of likes for board
{
Print "$c";
}
}
?>
```

The first part gets a users name and board details (board as in a photo album).

the second part joins that data with another sql table that counts the number of likes that board has.

Both are displayed as a name and a score represented by a number.

By default they are ordered by the date of creation. I'd like to be able to order them by the score. However, since the score is determined in the second part of the code, I don't know how to achieve it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is of course to query both at once in the first place, via a `LEFT JOIN` against a subquery returning the count per `board_id`:

```
SELECT
  board.*,
  /* Your PHP code will retrieve the likes count via this alias `numlikes` as in $info['numlikes'] */
  numlikes
FROM
  board
  LEFT JOIN (
    /* Subquery returns count per board_id */
    SELECT pins.board_id, COUNT(source_user_id) AS numlikes
    FROM
     likes
     INNER JOIN pins ON pins.id = likes.pin_id
    GROUP BY pins.board_id
  ) likes ON board.id = likes.board_id
ORDER BY numlikes
```

It is nearly always *significantly* more efficient to perform a single query rather than *n* queries in a loop. You should strive to do so whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one query

```
SELECT board.*, count(likes.source_user_id) as score
    FROM board
    INNER JOIN pins
        ON pins.board_id = board.id
    INNER JOIN likes 
        ON pins.id = likes.pin_id
ORDER BY score
```